# Angular 5 - When tried to access http://localhost:4200 in browser It shows "cannot GET / "

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, routes, angular5

These are the steps I've followed:

```
1. Installed Node Js
2. npm install -g @angular/cli
3. In F:/Angular -> ng new hellowworldapp
4. In F:/Angular/hellowworldapp -> ng serve
```

When I open http://localhost:4200/ I'm getting this error in the browser:

> Cannot GET /**

Then I've tried to ***uninstall and reinstall*** but I still have no clue what's happening.

Thanks in advance.

[View Compile success Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obLf2.png)

My *package.json* file is:

```
{
  "name": "hellowworldapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your console output? what happens if you run `ng serve --open`?

Comment: Can you check the dependencies in package.json? and some console output please

Comment: check if webpack compiled successfully on ngserve. then post a screen shot as well

Comment: update screenshot and package.json... @antoniogarcia

Comment: F12 in the browser and check the errors one

Comment: May be some wrong configuration in routes??

Comment: Do you have permissions on `index.html` file and `index.html` should be at `root`. Please check those permissions once.

Comment: No errors in browser console. Do have access to index.html and it exist in root only.

Comment: Where can I caheck for Routes configuration... I think Routes issue is related to Nodejs... Am totally confused..